# SQL get ids with minim 3 common values

Tags: mysql, sql, database

Can someone help me to get all ids with the same color from this table?
Thank you

[image]

Should return 1, 3, 9

Comment: _Same color ids_ - same as what?

Comment: As other id from other rows

Comment: Just one common color, or all of them?

Comment: I have to store in my database products and their colors, one product can have one or more colors. So, I made a table product_color where I store product id and color id, also I have another two tables with products and color
Now I need to select products with same color, can you help me with that?

Comment: Selected products should have the same colors and minimum 3 colors

Comment: Product 2 has 3 colors, product 9 has 3 colors. (The have 2 colors in common. Do yo mean they should have 3 colors in common.) What's the expected result if product 1, 3 and 9 share 3 colors, and product 11 and 12 share 3 other colors?

Comment: I need to write a SQL query to extract the products with 3 common colors. (Meaning products having the same colors but not less than three)
From my point of view, the result for your example should be 1, 3, 9, 11, 12

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try next query:

```
SELECT 
    p1.product_id p1
FROM `product_colors` p1
JOIN `product_colors` p2 ON p1.product_id <> p2.product_id AND  p1.color_id = p2.color_id
GROUP BY p1.product_id, p2.product_id 
HAVING COUNT(distinct p1.color_id) > 2
order by p1.product_id
;
```

Check it on [SQLize.online](https://sqlize.online/?phpses=null&sqlses=5503392c6f254cfde5b0d1abf2657912&php_version=null&sql_version=mysql80)